# Pipe stream directly to filesystem when downloading file in browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, http, fetch-api

I'm trying to download large file using chrome and would like to use stream to pipe it to the filesystem so it won't consume browser's RAM. Examples that I found so far, as I understand preloads everything to the RAM, and then save it to the filesystem, like:

```
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([byte], { type: 'text/csv' }));
link.download = reportName;
link.click();
```

Also I can't use `<a href=http://... />` because I need to pass authorization header with my request.

Comment: Note that there the question itself points to another possible solution using a ServiceWorker as middle-man to get a streaming *Content-type: Attachment* response. Though if you want to go this road the best is probably to use [Jimmy Warting's implementation](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js) directly. But anyway, in your case of using Chrome, `showSaveFilePicker()` should work fine.